# Proving a set is open using epsilon delta

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

If  $f:R \to R $ is continuous and $r_0 \in R $. Prove that {$x:f(x) \ne r_0$} is an open set.

Pf:Let $A=${$x:f(x) \ne r_0$}

If f is continuous then $\exists \delta >0 : \lvert x-x_0 \rvert < \delta  \implies \lvert f(x)-f(x_0) \rvert < \epsilon$

Let $a \in A$, then $f(a) \ne r_0 $

Let $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2} \lvert f(a)-r_0 \rvert >0$

We have to prove that {$x: \lvert x-a \rvert <\delta $} $\subset A$

Since f is continuous, therefore {$f(x):\lvert f(x)-f(a) \rvert <\frac{\epsilon}{2}$}

Consider that $\lvert f(a)-r_0 \rvert \le \lvert f(x)-r_0 \rvert + \lvert f(x)-f(a) \rvert$

or $2 \epsilon < \lvert f(x) -r_0 \rvert + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

$\therefore \lvert f(x)-r_0 \rvert > \frac{3 \epsilon}{2}$ and this implies $f(x) \ne r_0$ and {$x:\lvert x-a \rvert< \delta$} $\subset A$ or every point of x in A has a neighborhood inside A, thus A is open

Comment: The logic here is not clear, although I think you have the kernel of a good idea. Try writing it out again and avoid non sequiturs. For instance, "If f is continuous then there exists $\delta$ ...": it is not at all clear what $x_0$ you are talking about or what $\epsilon$. Or "Since f in continuous, therefore { ... }" : this makes no sense.

Comment: @SimonS that's just the definition of a continuous function

Comment: I am well versed with real analysis and know the definitions. I find it hard to follow the logic of what you have written. To look at the second example I gave "Since f is continuous, therefore { ... }". What about that set? The sentence as written is incoherent as you haven't said what continuity of f actually implies. Are you saying the set has some particular property?